# Ruby on Rails - Roo gem | Issue opening active record attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, roo, roo-gem

Status:

- I have a simple new Ruby On Rails App
- I need to import some data from MS Excel in .xlsx format
- I programmed an uploading to ActiveRecord as attachment via an attribute called 'excel'
- I found a `gem` called `Roo` which should do the opening of the attachment
- ...via: `Roo::Excelx.open()` command
- Then executes the accessing part of the file

Issue:
`Roo::Excel.open()` doesnt work for:

1. `Roo::Excel.open(excel)`
2. `Roo::Excel.open(excel.attachment)`

What is the correct command to execute to open the `ActiveRecord::Attachment`?

Comment: I get: 
TypeError in Admin::KirschExcelsController#import
no implicit conversion of ActiveStorage::Attachment into String

I try also: Roo::Excelx.new(excel.attachment) & Roo::Excelx.new(excel)

Answer (score 1):

how about do this?

```rb
ModelName.excel.open do |file|
 xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
end
```

Comment: I agree with this approach but you might want to add a bit more explanation as to why/how this works.

Comment: i actually do not know the more technical detail of that, but what i know is that open method does turn the file into object stream so we can read that using the roo gem. that's why i used like that usually on my works also.

Comment: Right that was my point. You can explain how this works because you just did in the comment. Your comment is much better post content then "how about this?". A good answer should explain why it is an answer rather than ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got an answer outside of Stackoverflow which was this:

`Roo::Spreadsheet.open(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(excel.key), extension: 'xlsx')`

I loaded one row from the Excel so must change code but opening it seemed to have worked! :-)